# A question about conjugate Sylow p-subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

I'm working on an exercise and am wondering if the following result is true.

Let $G$ a finite group and $p$ a prime number. Furthermore, let $Q$ be the group generated by all Sylow p-subgroups of $G$. Is it true that for a Sylow p-subgroup $P$, $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ are conjugate in $Q$? Here $g \in G$ is arbitrary.

I have shown that $Q$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and I know that $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ are Sylow p-subgroups, but I do not how/if this information is useful here.

Comment: Yeah of course, because $P$ and $gPg^{-1}$ are also Sylow $p$-subgroups of $Q$.

Comment: Well, that will certainly do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Note that your $Q$ equals $O^p(G)$, the smallest normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $G/N$ is  a $p'$-group (that is $|G:N|$ not divisible by $p$).